# FancyVerb error when % at end, when using \DefineVerbatimEnvironment

Tags: line-breaking, fancyvrb

This MWE gives an error when `%` is at the end the line as show below

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Xsmall}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
\begin{document}
\begin{Xsmall}
test
\end{Xsmall}%  ------> This causes the error
\end{document}
```

Then `pdflatex` gives

```
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)) (./foo.aux)
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `%\end{}' between \end{Xsmall} and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}                                                      
l.11 \end{Xsmall}%
```

Of course the solution is not to put `%` there. But life is not that simple. I use another software to help me generate these tex file. And this software keeps adding this `%` there each time. If I remove it, and reload the tex file again into it, it will add this `%` again.

My question is, is there something I can change in the definition of the `Xsmall` above,  such that adding this `%` do not cause a problem compiling it? Some kind of a trick or option or macro?

Again, I have to use this other software (it is Scientific word) but I also need to use this macro and be able to compile my file using tex live. There is no way to tell SW not to keep adding `%` at end of lines like this. I tried. It just keeps adding `%` each time.

Here is file list

```
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fancybox.sty    2010/05/15 1.4
fancyvrb.sty    2008/02/07
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
```

TL 2015 on Linux.

Comment: You could try with a `search-replace` function with `sed` (or any other programs available in your system) before each compilation to remove the `%`  from the document.  I tried this on my terminal: 
`sed -i  's/end{Xsmall}\%/end{Xsmall}/g'  <file> | pdflatex <file>`

Comment: I'm afraid that the solution is “don't type `%` in that position”. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for help from Scientific Word support, they gave me a work around for the Latex problem in my question. I post it here, in case someone in the future have to deal with it. Here is the answer

> Add a space after the encapsulated TeX field.  The % at the end
>   suppresses a normally unwanted white space in the typeset results.

So I just needed to add one space here:

```
\begin{Xsmall}
test
\end{Xsmall} <----- ADD ONE SPACE HERE
```

Now Scientific word do not add a `%`  !

Case closed. So I get clean compile.

Comment: thanks for posting the fix.  i tried running latex putting a space between the `} %` and it had no useful effect.  so the workaround has to be applied in sw -- it the file gets to tex, it's too late.  (we've had to get sw to make some fixes, and they've been pretty good about it; the worst problem was when they left expansions from `tcilatex`, complete with comments, in index entries.  *never* put a `%` comment in an index entry!  it gets through `makeindex` and blows up in the middle of `\printindex`; *very* confusing!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton  yes, this fix is specific for SW. in SW it has what it calls a `TexField`. It is used to allow one to enter raw latex in the document itself. But SW was adding `%` to the end of the line, even though the raw Latex was inside a TexField. Adding one white space, told SW not to add `%` any more to end of line, when it saves the document as Latex file. So I am able to compile it using TexLive. This all applies to SW 5.5. They have a new major version called 6.0 now, released few months ago, which I do not use. Version 6 is based on XML.

Comment: @barbarabeeton  if the Latex document in SW is saved as what is called `Portable Latex`, then tcilatex is not used. tcilatex is only used when one saves the document as `SW/SWP/SN`. I never do this. I always choose `Portable Latex`.

Comment: what you say is true, but some of the definitions from `tcilatex` used to be carried through to the "portable" version, inadvisedly.  that has now been fixed, but it was a real problem for a while.  fortunately, the support team was responsive once they saw the bad results.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem with Sweave
It was removed after I added the lines

```
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}
```

to the preamble.